# Python return troubles

Tags: python, function, return

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

My code come's up as `x not defined`. What i'm trying to do is get the result of `x` in `add1` and pass it to the `doub` function. I have searched and read up on this as much as possible, I know I am missing something simply so please point me in the right direction.

```
def main():
    value = (int)(input('Enter a number '))
    add1(value)
    doub(x)

def add1(value):
    x = value + 1
    return x


def doub (x):
    return x*2

main()
```

Comment: also, `(int)(input('Enter a number '))` looks too much like `c`.  `int(input('Enter a number '))` is much more normal in python code.

Comment: Why not just `return value + 1`?

Comment: `x` only exists as a name for an object in the scope of `add1`. You return the object, and would need to assign another name for it outside of `add1` if you ever want to talk about its value again.

Comment: in main() x is not defined.  You need something like this: x = add1(value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def main():
    value = int(input('Enter a number '))
    #This is more pythonic; use the int() function instead of (int)         
    doub(add1(value))

def add1(value):
    x = value + 1
    return x


def doub (x):
    return x*2

main()
```

Comment: hi linusg,thx for your response, i tried this and after i input a number nothing but >>> shows up.

Comment: Yes, that's because you have no `print` statement in your code. Try replacing `doub(add1(value))` with `print(doub(add1(value)))`

Comment: You are right, this did work. Thank you very much for your help it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`x` only exists within the `add1` function. All your `main` function knows is the *value* that's returned from calling add1, not the name of the variable it was previously stored in. You need to assign that value to a variable, and pass that into `doub`:

```
result = add1(value)
doub(result)
```

Also note, Python is not C; there's no such thing as typecasting. `int` is a function that you call on a value:

```
value = int(input('Enter a number '))
```

Comment: 'Also note, Python is not C; there's no such thing as typecasting. int is a function that you call on a value:
value = int(input('Enter a number '))' ------------ Noted. Btw thx for ur response.